# Python errors confusing a Python noobie

Tags: python

Literally started learning Python today and I'm about ready to pull my hair out over errors I'm not understanding.

Here are the errors I am getting when I try to run the script:

[image]

And here is the script in question:

```
primes = []
x = raw_input('Enter the max value to check for primes: ')

for num in range(2, x+1):
    if len(primes) == 0:
        primes.append(num)
    else: 
        for prime in primes:
           if (num % prime == 0):
               break
        primes.append(num)

for number in primes:
    print number
```

From the errors received so far, it looks like I cannot declare a blank list, and it doesn't like my input method.  I copied these lines more or less out of a tutorial where they worked, and I am confused as to why they work there but not here.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of python are you using? The above code contains Python 2 specific stuff. If you're using Python 3 that would explain it

Comment: How about putting your error messages into the question?  Uploading an image of the text of the errors is probably why you got downvoted.

Comment: Image was easier than typing it out.  I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messages you posted start with a "command not found", which implies you are running this Python script not in Python, but in a shell.  To fix it, either run something like `python Question7.py`, or add `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the very first line of the script (this is known as a shebang line, and tells the interpreter to let Python run the script instead).

Answer (score 1):

Only problem that I faced was

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Fix this by:

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter the max value to check for primes: '))
```

Comment: my version of python: Python 2.7.3

Comment: So you probably aren't aware of the difference between the Source Code Editor Window of IDLE or PyCharm, and a REPL like the Python Shell.